# Strikethrough text ListView cannot find symbol method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, strikethrough

I'm doing a to-do list and I wanted add a strikethrough effect after double tapping the `ListView` but it gave me an error which says the following.

> Cannot find symbol                listView.setPaintFlags(listView.getPaintFlags() _ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG)

How Can I solve it?

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    private GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setPaintFlags(listView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            return true;
        }
    });
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            return gd.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the `ListView` has the method which provides the strikethrough feature on its items. I think the `TextView` inside an item of your `ListView` has the attribute which should work like the following.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

You might also consider implementing your custom adapter to get the reference of the `TextView` and strikethrough the view using the code above.

Comment: yea it worked after listening to your advice thank you so much!!

Comment: Great to know that I could help. You are welcome. :)

Comment: It worked but just work on the first item I don't know why :( Sorry I'm still new to Android.

Comment: I would recommend implementing a custom adapter for your `ListVIew`. You can check the [tutorial here](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial) for understanding how to implement a custom adapter. Once you have your custom adapter of your `ListView`, you will have better controls over your list items.